# Hibernate mapping issue with multiple lists in a single class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to create multiple lists that map to a single class.
This is the POJO class

```
public class ModuleQuestion {
    private Module module;
    private int id;
    private List<Question> qLevel2;
    private List<Question> qLevel3;

    //getter and setter 
}
```

and Mapping file is

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.pro.model.ModuleQuestion" table="MODULE_QUE">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="module" class="com.pro.model.Module">
            <column name="MODULE"></column>
        </many-to-one>

        <list name="qLevel2" cascade="all" >
            <key column="ID"></key>
            <index />
            <one-to-many class="com.pro.model.Question" />
        </list>

        <list name="qLevel3" cascade="all" >
            <key column="ID"></key>
            <index />
            <one-to-many class="com.pro.model.Question" />
        </list>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

It allows me to insert the data but when I fetch the data, it gives error org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection.
Is there any way to fetch the data without creating multiple tables for multiple list?

Comment: Set level in `Question` instead and keep just one list.

Comment: But it will be typical to get questions of particular level. It will be required to access all questions.

Comment: Then you write specific queries for that.